# Can cnosdb automatically migrate cold data?

Tags: cnosdb

I found a command similar to copy vnode to node in the cnosdb document, but it doesn't seem to meet my requirements. I need to migrate some cold data, but currently I don't know which vnodes the cold data is on, so this command is difficult for me to use. I hope to implement this function.

I have reviewed the documentation for cnosdb.But it doesn't meet my needs.I hope to implement this function or provide some existing methods